# Where to announce/discuss stuff?

Tags: discussion

I've just received an email from the microsoft insider program, where they spotlight windows 10 IoT support for Arduino

> We’re also excited to announce our partnership with Arduino, making Windows 10 the world’s first Arduino-certified operating system. Learn more about Windows Remote Arduino and Windows Virtual Shields for Arduino and get started here.

^Sorry for not having the links in it.

Is there anywhere on Arduino Stack Exchange to announce this? I was tempted to create a question as announcement, as I think it's quite interesting for everyone who's busy with arduino. I'm not sure if announcing it in chat will do.
I found that there are little chat-rooms on the site. Is this a topic worth a chatroom? And will the chatroom stay even if everyone leaves it for a moment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blockquote you included in your question reads to me like part of an advertisement, so there's really not a good place for it on this site. If that's not the message you want to spread (i.e. if I'm misunderstanding what you mean by "announcement"), please let me know.

You are of course welcome to ask questions on the main site about Arduino/Windows 10 integration when the time comes.

To answer your procedural question, chat content never goes away, although it can get soft-deleted just like Q&A posts or remain visible in a read-only state. For more info, see [the chat FAQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention).